# SQL Select Adding a new row with difference between numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that give the sum between years but I want to add a new row at the end of each *TARMA* that give the differences between the years.

Here is the query:

```
 Select  
     VPC.Armazem as TARMA
    ,YEAR(VPC.DATA) as DataTotal
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 1 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as ADITIVADA
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 2 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as X98
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 3 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END)as X95
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 4 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as XGAS
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 5 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as XGPL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 6 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as XAGR
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 7 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as MISTURA
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 9 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as XAQ
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 10 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as ADIESEL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 11 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as ADBLUE
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 12 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as O95
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 13 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as O98

WHERE 
    (MONTH(VPC.DATA) >= MONTH('2015-09-01') AND MONTH(VPC.DATA) <= MONTH('2015-09-30'))
    and (YEAR(VPC.DATA) >= YEAR('2014-09-01') AND YEAR(VPC.DATA) <= YEAR('2015-09-30'))
    and VPT.armazem IN ('454','457')
    and FACT_VD NOT IN ('A', 'I', 'G', 'M')
GROUP BY
    YEAR(VPC.DATA)
    ,VPC.Armazem
ORDER BY
    VPC.Armazem
    ,YEAR(VPC.DATA)
```

And here is the result without the difference: 
[Result][1]

For example:

> TARMA: 454 for X98
>
> 2014: 1849.14077
>
> 2015: 2571.47750
>
> Difference: -722,33673

I'm using MS SQL.
Is it with a `UNION`?

How can I get the difference?

Comment: you have 3 years in your example.. what do you mean by differences

Comment: yeah I don't get what you mean by "difference".   I recommend that you edit your post and add your desired results.

Comment: Sorry, got the correct image now and an example for the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
;with dados as (

    Select  
     VPC.Armazem as TARMA
    ,YEAR(VPC.DATA) as DataTotal1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 1 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaADITIVADA
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 2 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaX98
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 3 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END)as SomaX95
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 4 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaXGAS
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 5 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaXGPL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 6 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaXAGR
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 7 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaMISTURA
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 9 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaXAQ
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 10 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaADIESEL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 11 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaADBLUE
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 12 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaO95
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN VP.COMBUSTIVEL = 13 THEN VPL.QTD ELSE 0 END) as SomaO98
    ,row_number() over (partition by VPC.Armazem order by YEAR(VPC.DATA) ASC) as NAno

WHERE 
    (MONTH(VPC.DATA) >= MONTH('2015-09-01') AND MONTH(VPC.DATA) <= MONTH('2015-09-30'))
    and (YEAR(VPC.DATA) >= YEAR('2014-09-01') AND YEAR(VPC.DATA) <= YEAR('2015-09-30'))
    and VPT.armazem IN ('454','457')
    and FACT_VD NOT IN ('A', 'I', 'G', 'M')
GROUP BY
    YEAR(VPC.DATA)
    ,VPC.Armazem

)

SELECT
      anosDetalhados.TARMA as TARMA
     ,anosDetalhados.DataTotal1 as DataTotal
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaADITIVADA) as ADITIVADA 
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaX98) as X98
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaX95) as X95
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaXGAS) as XGAS
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaXGPL) as XGPL
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaXAGR) as XAGR
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaMISTURA) as MISTURA
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaXAQ) as XAQ
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaADIESEL) as ADIESEL
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaADBLUE) as ADBLUE
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaO95) as O95
     ,SUM(anosDetalhados.SomaO98) as O98
FROM dados as anosDetalhados (nolock)
GROUP BY
    anosDetalhados.DataTotal1
    ,anosDetalhados.TARMA

UNION ALL

SELECT
     ano1.TARMA as TARMA
    ,NULL  as DataTotal
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaADITIVADA-ano2.SomaADITIVADA, 0)) as ADITIVADA 
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaX98-ano2.SomaX98, 0)) as X98
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaX95-ano2.SomaX95, 0)) as X95
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaXGAS-ano2.SomaXGAS, 0)) as XGAS
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaXGPL-ano2.SomaXGPL, 0)) as XGPL
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaXAGR-ano2.SomaXAGR, 0)) as XAGR
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaMISTURA-ano2.SomaMISTURA, 0)) as MISTURA
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaXAQ-ano2.SomaXAQ, 0)) as XAQ
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaADIESEL-ano2.SomaADIESEL, 0)) as ADIESEL
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaADBLUE-ano2.SomaADBLUE, 0)) as ADBLUE
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaO95-ano2.SomaO95, 0)) as O95
    ,SUM(coalesce(ano1.SomaO98-ano2.SomaO98, 0)) as O98
FROM dados as ano1 (nolock)
LEFT JOIN dados as ano2 on ano1.TARMA=ano2.TARMA and ano1.NAno > ano2.NAno
GROUP BY
    ano1.TARMA
ORDER BY
    TARMA
   ,anosDetalhados.DataTotal1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your query as a subquery (without the `order by`), you can do something like this:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*,
       (additava - lag(additava) over (partition by Armazem order by DataTotal) ) as additava_diff,
       . . .
from cte;
```

Note:  `lag()` requires SQL Server 2012+.

EDIT:

Prior to SQL Server 2012+, you could do:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*,
       (additava - cte2.additava) as additava_diff,
       . . .
from cte outer apply
     (select top 1 cte.*
      from cte cte2
      where cte2.Armazem = cte.Armazem and cte2.DataTotal < cte.DataTotal
      order by cte2.DataTotal
     ) cte2
```

Comment: Unfortunately the server I'm working is running a older version

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the difference in a separate query and then just "add" the rows to your results, you can use the "UNION ALL" between your queries.  "UNION ALL" will just combine the 2 result sets.  Using just "UNION" will cause SQL Server to attempt to de-duplicate the rows in the 2 result sets.

Comment: But I don't know how to calculate the differences, that's where I'm having a problem :s